# Drawing path trails between two points

Tags: d3.js

Is there a simple way with `D3` to draw 'trails' between two points during a transition?

In other words, I transtition between scatter plots. When I make the transition, one set of points is replaced by another, with tweens on the update.

How can I create paths between the old points and the new ones on update? Will it be necessary to use `stroke-dasharray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I guess it depends on your definition of "simple", but you can use the transition's `start` and `end` events along with a custom tween to add a line when the transition starts, update its endpoint as the transition progresses, and remove it when the transition ends.

```
circle.transition().duration(2000)
  .attrTween("cx", function() {
    var start = d3.select(this).attr("cx"),
        i = d3.interpolate(start, 200)
    return function(t) {
        var current = i(t);
        svg.select("line.tmp").attr("x2", current);
        return current;
    }
  })
  .each("start", function() {
    svg.append("line").attr("class", "tmp")
        .attr("x1", d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
        .attr("y1", d3.select(this).attr("cy"))
        .attr("y2", d3.select(this).attr("cy"));
  })
  .each("end", function() {
    svg.select("line.tmp").remove();
  });
```

Complete proof of concept [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pyxcp2gt/). To make this work for multiple transitions, you'd need to add something that allows to distinguish between the lines, e.g. a class based on data bound to the respective point or keep explicit references.